# Centering multi div

Tags: html, css, centering

I am trying to center multiples div so that it works a cross all browser.

```
<style>
.boxContent {
    width: 288px;    
    height: 288px;
    background-color: #777;
    margin: 2px;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boxContainer {
    background-color: #333;
    text-align: center;
    display: table;
}
</style>  
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="boxContainer center">
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asdas</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asdas</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
                <div class="boxContent">asda</div>
            </div>            
        </div>    
    </div>
</body>
```

So far this works how i wanted on google chrome but it doesnt look the same when on firefox and looks even worse on IE 10.

Thank you

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y1p6oszu/)

Comment: Working with no problems in Firefox: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNEYbz So what exactly are you asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove the

```
display: table;
```

and you will get the same result.

Comment: Nearly there, both chrome and Firefox are displaying the same layout but it doesn't seem to work for IE 10.0.14. Thanks

Comment: are you using normalize.css?

Comment: Na i am not using that. Should i use it?, as i never heard of that before.